# Photo Asset Iteration

Tags: swift, swift-framework

I'm messing with some photo assets and I am trying to go through my camera roll and print out all the assets from every single photo. I know it would need to be a for loop but just not entirely sure how to write it

`guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else { return nil }`

```
let sectionType = sections[selectedIndexPath.section]
let item = selectedIndexPath.item
let assets: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>
let title: String

switch sectionType {
case .all:
  assets = allPhotos
  title = AlbumCollectionSectionType.all.description

case .smartAlbums, .userCollections:
  let album =
    sectionType == .smartAlbums ? smartAlbums[item] : userCollections[item]
  assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: album, options: nil)
  title = album.localizedTitle ?? ""
}
print("\(assets)")
print("\(assets.object(at: 0))")
return PhotosCollectionViewController(assets: assets, title: title, coder: coder)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.enumerateObjects` on `assets` to loop through them:

```
assets.enumerateObjects { (asset, count, stop) in
    //asset is the PHAsset
}
```

Comment: @JesseRae did you get a chance too see if this answers your question?